# Are overhead door bottom seals with interior beads effective at stopping leaks?

Tags: garage, garage-door, weather-resistant

I need to replace my T-style (two channel) garage door seal. My garage floor is uneven and water seeps in on one side.

Old seal is "U" type. I've seen a "U+O" type, with an O inside attached to the bottom of the U form. One manufacturer claims it's more heavy duty against weather and creates better seal with extra cushion. However, amazon had some reviewers saying the U+O type kept falling out of the channel and off the door.

Does U=O really keep water out better than just a U type?

Is the added weight of the "O" a fatal flaw?

Comment: You could always slip a length of 1/2" or 3/4" foam rope caulk inside a standard seal. It weighs almost nothing. Weight isn't really a concern, though. Just adjust your springs accordingly.

Comment: Good idea that might work also. Cheaper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had a garage door with U seal channel that leaked some water on one side. More water leaked when the garage door was open, so I knew the door was slowing it down; but nothing I did with the garage door would stop it.

If your goal is to stop the water from coming in, my recommendation is either to fix the concrete outside the garage door by installing a water drain channel (the right but expensive solution) or use a seal that attaches to the floor (the inexpensive way) Photo from example product on Amazon, since I don't want to advertise anything specific:

[image]

Regarding the U vs U+O, the U rubber flattens pretty quickly since it's under compression when the door is closed and the addition of O inside should help resist the deterioration due to pressure. If it's installed correctly into the proper size channel, you shouldn't have issues with it falling out of the channel.

Comment: I forgot to mention I also have to sweep water out when my wife's car comes in with snow on it. The floor seal is a great idea but not for my case. Whenever we repour garage or driveway floors I'll go with the drain. Thanks good answer.